# gem:koala: this authorization code has expired. [HTTP 400]:

Tags: ruby, heroku, koala

Why does this work on my local machine but not on the heroku server?

```
  def set_access_token
    # get the access token from wherever we can
    @access_token ||= (set_oauth_data && @oauth_access_token) || (set_facebook_cookies && @cookie_access_token)
  end
```

Error:

```
 `get_token_from_server'
2013-01-03T08:54:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Koala::Facebook::OAuthTokenRequestError - type: OAuthException, code: 100, message: This authorization code h
as expired. [HTTP 400]:
```

Comment: From where do you get the token?